# Finite conjugacy classes in a certain group with three generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Def. We say that group G has non-trivial finite conjugacy class if there is a conjugacy class $C=\lbrace g_i \rbrace$ such that $g_i \neq 1$ of G with $|C|<\infty$. Let G be group

$$<a,b,c \quad | \quad c^n=1, [a,b]=c >$$

Suppose $n>1$. How can I prove G has no non-trivial finite conjugacy class?

Comment: The group $G$  is an HNN-extension with base group $H=\langle a,c \rangle$, and the subgroups $\langle a \rangle$ and $\langle ac \rangle$ are malnormal in $H$. I think in that situation the result follows from a result of Karass and Solitar. See the discussion: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/159308

Comment: And you also need the fact that $\langle a \rangle$ and $\langle ac \rangle$ are disjoint.